# Write in a <p> api response

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to get a response from this api :
https://spen.tk/api/v1/isScamLink

The api response looks like this :

```json
{"status":200,"result":true,"linkFound":""}
```

I want to get the result part into a var and use it in a paragraph in HTML.

This is my js code in the site :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://spen.tk/api/v1/isScamLink?link=' + document.getElementById("box").value,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      var result = response.data.total;
      var final = $('#result').text(result);
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

It sais this error :
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total')`

Comment: Your question doesn't show what you have tried yet and where you are stuck. Please read through this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Given you already got the response, it will already be stored in a variable! Could you be more specific about the problem you are facing.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my question now. Hopefully it's more clear.

Comment: This is a lot better !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data will be in `response.result`

```js
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://spen.tk/api/v1/isScamLink?link=https://google.com',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response.result)
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response json doesn't contain the key 'data', that's why you're getting error.